# Linear map that maps a circle to a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, circles, rotations

Is it true that a linear map $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ that maps a circle to a circle is the composition of a rotation and scaling?
I mean rotation around the origin and scaling centered at the origin.

Comment: What do you think?  Items 2 and 3 in the "Asking a good question" box that popped up when you clicked "Ask Question" are:  "2. Provide details and any research" and "3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried"  So what was your research and what have you tried?

Comment: @EricTowers I thought that the first centre C must be mapped to the second one C'  otherwise the origin would be translated. Then I fix a point P on the first circle and I name $P'=f(P)$. Once I draw the two points C', P' I can see that $f$ is determined by those two transformations. I don't know if this is correct and how to formalize the intuition. Thank you.

Comment: You say "rotation"and tag "linear-transformation", so do you mean "rotation around the origin"?  I ask because there need not be a rotation taking $C$ to $C'$ in your comment.  If the rotation can be around any center, then there are infinitely many rotations that take $C$ to $C'$.  Similarly, is "scaling" centered at the origin or can scaling be centered anywhere?

Comment: @EricTowers I mean rotation around the origin and scaling centered at the origin

Comment: You should update your Question to incorporate the improvements that are scattered in these comments.  Use the "edit" link just below and to the right of the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the answer to your question is no, because you may need to do a flip as well. If you add that, the answer becomes yes.

Here is an elementary argument (see below for a "scientific" one):

Step 1) Center goes to center: Consider a parallelogram inscribed into your circle. It is automatically a rectangle, and intersection of its diagonal is the center of the original circle, which we will call $C$. Its image under any linear map is a parallelogram inscribed in the image circle, hence also a rectangle. It's diagonals intersect at $C'$, the center of the image circle. The image of the intersection of diagonals is the intersection of diagonals of the image. So the center goes to the center, $C'=f(C)$.

Step 2) Case 1: If $C$, the center of original circle, is the origin, then after composing with a rescaling you have a map that sends original circle to itself. Such a map preserves lengths, and so must be a rotation or a composition of a flip and a rotation.
Case 2: If $C$ is not the origin, then there exists a rotation and rescaling that takes $C'$ to $C$. Composing $f$ with them you have now a map that takes $C$ to $C$ and a circle around $C$ to a concentric circle. The vector from origin to $C$ is fixed; since the map is linear the whole line from origin to $C$ is fixed; so in fact the circle in question is also fixed. Consider tangent lines to the circle parallel to $OC=OC'$. These lines are either taken to themselves or exchanged. In the first case the composite map is identity, and original map is rotation composed with rescaling; in the second case it is a flip through the line $OC$ and the original map is composition of rescaling, rotation and this flip.

Now, in general if an affine map from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ takes a sphere to a sphere then after pre and post composing with rescalings and  translations it takes the standard sphere through the origin to itself. This means result is distance-preserving, so lies in the orthogonal group $O(n)$. This in turn means that the map is a composition of a rescaled element of orthogonal group and a translation (any initial translation can be commuted out to a translation acting after the linear map; this is a manifestation of the structure of affine group as a semidirect product of translations and linear maps). If the original map is actually linear, instead of just affine, then the translation bit is automatically trivial; thus proving that the map itself is a rescaled element of orthogonal group  (aka a composition of a rotation with possibly a reflection and/or a rescaling).